# Is there any limitation of using sampler2D array in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm using a sampler2d array in my glsl program:

```
uniform sampler2D diffuseMaps[100];
```

And I passed the textures like below:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < textures.size() ; i++)
{ 
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i]->textureId);

    std::string name = "diffuseMaps[" + std::to_string(i) + "]";
    GLuint loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader->getHandle(), name.c_str());
    glUniform1i(loc, i);
}
```

It works good, I have **80 textures** and OpenGl has not more than **GL_TEXTURE31** index.

Does it only works on my hardware (GTX 1070Ti)?

What about other hardware?

Is there any limitation in number of textures that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limit on how many texture one can create, but there is a limit on how many textures can be used by a shader at the same time. This is defined by [`MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGet.xhtml). In OpenGL 4.X, at least 16 textures can be used, although GPUs might allow you to use more. At the time of writing, it is very unlikely that any hardware will allow you to sample 80 textures at the same time.

When you need more textures, you should consider using an [array texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Array_Texture) which supports at least 256 layer. Another option would be to merge the textures into a 3D texture.

Comment: Very useful thanks, just another question , I do glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i); and when "i" is bigger 32 then i have GL_ACTIVE_TEXTURE and GL_MULTISAMPLE .... is this a problem ?

Comment: *is this a problem*: It depends. Does your hardware support more than 32 textures?

Comment: I mean when the i is bigger than 32 then actually i have glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE31)  , glActiveTexture(GL_ACTIVE_TEXTURE) , glActiveTexture(GL_MULTISAMPLE) ,...

Comment: glActiveTexture can just accept GL_TEXTURE0 ... GL_TEXTURE31

Comment: @masoudkhanlo: Got it now. I don't think that OpenGL has already thought about that. There are currently only 32 constants defined. But I wouldn't know of any hardware that supports more.

Comment: Great , anyway looks it works even for more than 32.

Comment: @masoudkhanlo: `glActiveTexture` is not limited to 32. Indeed, you shouldn't bother to use the enumerators, just `GL_TEXTURE0 + i`, with [the limit defined by `GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS`.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/30101/8240)